# Merge Rows Together wth same ID SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, subquery, common-table-expression

Outside of the sample below I'm actually running a query that pulls 39000 rows in 9 seconds.  I want to change the query to merge rows related to BusinessRuleCriteriaID into one row (In the sample provided all 9 rows should be one row). I can sacrifice a fair amount of timeliness to accomplish this. At max I want the query to take 2 minutes.
The fastest time I had was 30 minutes minutes doing joins in the ItemTagDescriptions and SegSubTags lists. Nothing i have tried has come near to 2 minutes.

The version of SQL used is SQL Server 2008.

```
   SELECT [BusinessRuleCriteriaID], [ItemType], [tag], [TagValue], Operator,
           [ESSubTag], [ES01], [ES02], [ES03], [ES04], [ES05], [ES06], [ES07], [ES08], [ES09], [ES10], [ES11], [ES12],
           [ITMSubTag], [ITM01],
           [RR4SubTag], [RR401], [RR402]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT crit.BusinessRuleCriteriaID, 
            crit.ItemType, 
            crit.tag,
            crit.TagValue,
            crit.Operator,
            case when seg.SegmentType = 'ES' then SegSubTags.list end AS [ESSubTag],
            case when seg.SegmentType = 'ITM' then SegSubTags.list end AS [ItemSubTag],
            case when seg.SegmentType = 'RR4' then SegSubTags.list end AS [RR4SubTag],
            c.CellName as [SegmentId],
            case when c.CellValue is not null and len(c.CellValue) > 0 Then c.CellValue
             Else ItemTagDescriptions.list
             End as [Tags]
        FROM
            BMT_BusinessRuleCriteria crit 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            BMT_MappingRuleServiceType it
        ON it.BusinessRuleCriteriaID = crit.BusinessRuleCriteriaID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            BMT_BusinessRuleSegment seg
        ON seg.BusinessRuleCriteriaID = crit.BusinessRuleCriteriaID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            BMT_BusinessRuleCell c
        ON c.BusinessRuleSegmentID = seg.BusinessRuleSegmentID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            BMT_BusinessRuleCellOption MT
        ON c.BusinessRuleCellId = MT.BusinessRuleCellId
        OUTER APPLY 
        ( 
        SELECT 
                IsNull(MT2.Tag, '{Unknown}') + ISNULL('=' + MT.TagValue, '') + ':' + IsNull(MT.CellValue, '') + ';' AS [text()] 
                FROM 
                    BMT_BusinessRuleCellOption MT
                WHERE 
                    MT.BusinessRuleCellId = MT.BusinessRuleCellId
                ORDER BY 
                    MT.BusinessRuleCellId 
                FOR XML PATH('')) ItemTagDescriptions (list) 
        OUTER APPLY 
        (
                SELECT IsNull(SegSubTag.Tag, '{Unknown}') + ' ' + ISNULL(SegSubTag.Operator, '') + ' ' + IsNull(SegSubTag.TagValue, '') + ';' as [text()]
                FROM 
                    BMT_BusinessRuleSegmentTag SegSubTag 
                WHERE 
                    SegSubTag.BusinessRuleSegmentID = seg.BusinessRuleSegmentID
                ORDER BY 
                    SegSubTag.BusinessRuleSegmentID 
                FOR XML PATH('')
        ) SegSubTags (list) 
            WHERE 
            crit.BusinessRuleCriteriaID = 489302
    ) AS ESTable
    PIVOT
    (
        max([Tags])
        FOR [SegmentId] IN ([ES01],[ES02],[ES03],[ES04],[ES05], [ES06], [ES07], [ES08], [ES09], [ES10], [ES11], [ES12], [ITM01], [RR401], [RR402])
    ) AS ESPivotTable
```

```html
    <table border='1'><body>
<tr><td>BusinessRuleCriteriaID</td><td>ItemType</td><td>tag</td><td>TagValue</td><td>Operator</td><td>ESSubTag</td><td>ES01</td><td>ES02</td><td>ES03</td><td>ES04</td><td>ES05</td><td>ES06</td><td>ES07</td><td>ES08</td><td>ES09</td><td>ES10</td><td>ES11</td><td>ES12</td><td>ItemSubTag</td><td>ITM01</td><td>RR4SubTag</td><td>RR401</td><td>RR402</td></tr>
<tr><td>489302</td><td>OP</td><td>DHOTIAP</td><td>NULL</td><td>present</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>{INFOSTOR}</td><td>NULL</td><td>88</td><td>45</td></tr>
<tr><td>489302</td><td>OP</td><td>DHOTIAP</td><td>NULL</td><td>present</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>PARARND present ;</td><td>PARARND:{INFOSTOR};</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td>489302</td><td>OP</td><td>DHOTIAP</td><td>NULL</td><td>present</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>PARACONT present ;</td><td>PARACONT:{INFOSTOR};</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td>489302</td><td>OP</td><td>DHOTIAP</td><td>NULL</td><td>present</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>PARAJUK present ;</td><td>PARAJUK:{INFOSTOR};</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td>489302</td><td>OP</td><td>DHOTIAP</td><td>NULL</td><td>present</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>PARAFUL present ;</td><td>PARAFUL:{INFOSTOR};</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td>489302</td><td>OP</td><td>DHOTIAP</td><td>NULL</td><td>present</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>PARANEK present ;</td><td>PARANEK:{INFOSTOR};</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td>489302</td><td>OP</td><td>DHOTIAP</td><td>NULL</td><td>present</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>PARANOID present ;</td><td>PARANOID:{INFOSTOR};</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td>489302</td><td>OP</td><td>DHOTIAP</td><td>NULL</td><td>present</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>PARATRAN present ;</td><td>PARATRAN:{INFOSTOR};</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td>489302</td><td>OP</td><td>DHOTIAP</td><td>NULL</td><td>present</td><td>TIKAPE not present ;TIKELP not present ;TIKRAP not present ;</td><td>GH</td><td>TEK</td><td>12</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>SSLYWA:3;REGFA:43;</td><td>SOLFAR:{Data};TENDE:{Data};</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>W</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
</body></table>

<BR><BR>

<table border='1'>
 <body>
  <tr>
   <td>BusinessRuleCriteriaID</td>
   <td>ItemType</td>
   <td>tag</td>
   <td>TagValue</td>
   <td>Operator</td>
   <td>ESSubTag</td>
   <td>ES01</td>
   <td>ES02</td>
   <td>ES03</td>
   <td>ES04</td>
   <td>ES05</td>
   <td>ES06</td>
   <td>ES07</td>
   <td>ES08</td>
   <td>ES09</td>
   <td>ES10</td>
   <td>ES11</td>
   <td>ES12</td>
   <td>ItemSubTag</td>
   <td>ITM01</td>
   <td>RR4SubTag</td>
   <td>RR401</td>
   <td>RR402</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>489302</td>
   <td>OP</td>
   <td>DHOTIAP</td>
   <td>NULL</td>
   <td>present</td>
   <td>TIKAPE not present ;TIKELP not present ;TIKRAP not present ;</td>
   <td>GH</td>
   <td>TEK</td>
   <td>12</td>
   <td>NULL</td>
   <td>NULL</td>
   <td>SSLYWA:3;REGFA:43;</td>
   <td>SOLFAR:{Data};TENDE:{Data};</td>
   <td>NULL</td>
   <td>NULL</td>
   <td>NULL</td>
   <td>NULL</td>
   <td>W</td>
   <td>PARARND present ;PARACONT present ;PARAJUK present ;PARAFUL present ;PARANEK present ;PARANOID present ;PARATRAN present ;</td>
   <td>{INFOSTOR};PARARND:{INFOSTOR};PARACONT:{INFOSTOR};PARAJUK:{INFOSTOR};PARAFUL:{INFOSTOR};PARANEK:{INFOSTOR};PARANOID:{INFOSTOR};PARATRAN:{INFOSTOR};</td>
   <td>NULL</td>
   <td>88</td>
   <td>45</td>
  </tr>
 </body>
</table>

<BR><BR>

<table border='1'><body>
<tr><td id='1'>BusinessRuleCriteriaID</td><td id='2'>ItemType</td><td id='3'>tag</td><td id='4'>TagValue</td><td id='5'>Operator</td><td id='6'>ESSubTag</td><td id='19'>ItemSubTag</td><td id='21'>RR4SubTag</td></tr>
<tr><td id='1'>489302</td><td id='2'>OP</td><td id='3'>DHOTIAP</td><td id='4'>NULL</td><td id='5'>present</td><td id='6'>NULL</td><td id='19'>NULL</td><td id='21'>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td id='1'>489302</td><td id='2'>OP</td><td id='3'>DHOTIAP</td><td id='4'>NULL</td><td id='5'>present</td><td id='6'>NULL</td><td id='19'>PARARND present ;</td><td id='21'>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td id='1'>489302</td><td id='2'>OP</td><td id='3'>DHOTIAP</td><td id='4'>NULL</td><td id='5'>present</td><td id='6'>NULL</td><td id='19'>PARACONT present ;</td><td id='21'>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td id='1'>489302</td><td id='2'>OP</td><td id='3'>DHOTIAP</td><td id='4'>NULL</td><td id='5'>present</td><td id='6'>NULL</td><td id='19'>PARAJUK present ;</td><td id='21'>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td id='1'>489302</td><td id='2'>OP</td><td id='3'>DHOTIAP</td><td id='4'>NULL</td><td id='5'>present</td><td id='6'>NULL</td><td id='19'>PARAFUL present ;</td><td id='21'>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td id='1'>489302</td><td id='2'>OP</td><td id='3'>DHOTIAP</td><td id='4'>NULL</td><td id='5'>present</td><td id='6'>NULL</td><td id='19'>PARANEK present ;</td><td id='21'>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td id='1'>489302</td><td id='2'>OP</td><td id='3'>DHOTIAP</td><td id='4'>NULL</td><td id='5'>present</td><td id='6'>NULL</td><td id='19'>PARANOID present ;</td><td id='21'>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td id='1'>489302</td><td id='2'>OP</td><td id='3'>DHOTIAP</td><td id='4'>NULL</td><td id='5'>present</td><td id='6'>NULL</td><td id='19'>PARATRAN present ;</td><td id='21'>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td id='1'>489302</td><td id='2'>OP</td><td id='3'>DHOTIAP</td><td id='4'>NULL</td><td id='5'>present</td><td id='6'>TIKAPE not present ;TIKELP not present ;TIKRAP not present ;</td><td id='19'>NULL</td><td id='21'>NULL</td></tr>
</body></table>
```

Edit: Added DataSample with pivot commented out

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing I would suggest is to re-write your query without the "DISTINCT" in it.  Use a GROUP BY clause instead as in my experience this tends to perform better.  Also could you post a sample data set from the query without the PIVOT statement.  It will help me identify the grouping problem you are having with BusinessRuleCriteriaID.

Comment: +added data sample without pivot. I believe a major part of why the data shows up on multiple lines is because each BusinessRuleCriteriaID can have multiple BusienssRuleSegmentIDs.

Comment: Yep - your duplicates aren't actually duplicates, each Row is returning a different value for ItemSubTag (PARARND:{INFOSTOR}, PARACONT:{INFOSTOR} etc.).  If you want to collapse the result set you will need to either exclude that column from your select or return some static value that will allow a DISTINCT or GROUP BY to collapse those rows.  Is the data in that column critical to your application?

Comment: yes the data is vital. The Idea is to concatenate all of the rows together. what we want to see is the result I have already listed in the second table.

Comment: I should add that even then you will still get two rows as there are two different values for ESSubTag.  in that case you could exclude records where ESSubTag is null.

Comment: If I were to exclude records where ESSubTag is null wouldn't that cut out the data within the ITM and RR4 SubTag Columns if data is present there in that row?

Comment: Yeah that is tricky - you really need to concatenate all those values before you join them to the BusinessRuleCriteria data.  You could build a set of scalar functions that take an input of the BusinessRuleCriteria and output the concatenated string you are looking for.  That way you can just call those functions in your select clause.  Might have some performance impact though.